# string.insert(contentsOf: at:) giving error

Tags: swift, string

I've been using the following code that is from the Apple website in a Swift 4 playground:

```
var mystring = "Hello there"
mystring.insert(contentsOf: "TEST".characters, at: 5)
```

This gives the error:

> Extraneous argument label 'contentsOf:' in call

with the following description in the playground:

> error: testsubstrings.playground:1:24: error: protocol 'Collection' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements str.insert(contentsOf: Collection, at: <#T##String.Index#>)

This is the same example that is on the Apple doc website. I can't figure out why it won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using Swift 4, the issue is largely being caused by your attempt to specific the index with an `Int` instead of a `String.Index`.

Your code works with the following changes:

```
var mystring = "Hello there"
mystring.insert(contentsOf: "TEST", at: mystring.index(mystring.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
```

Result:

> HelloTEST there

Working with string indexes is not simple.

Comment: Thanks - I can get this to now work in a playground using exactly the same as you have above.